# Sorted a list contains tuple in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list like this:

````
list = [('Betty', 42.5), ('Andrew', 46.5), ('Zach', 49), ('Cathy',     
42.5), ('Jay', 45.5), ('Kevin', 45), ('Cassie', 41), ('Matt', 44),     
('Jamie', 44.5), ('Xavier', 45.5), ('Peter', 45.5), ('John', 42.5), 
('Jamie', 40.5), ('Joe', 40.5), ('Ellen', 44.5), ('Nancy', 35), 
('Jay', 45), ('Bryce', 43.5), ('Gordon', 37), ('Gee', 42.5)]```
````

How I can sort it by name (if name is same, the one with higher score comes first) in Python?

I tried this but it doesn't sort by score if same name
`sorted(list)`

Comment: Please do not use builtin names for variable names: `list`

Comment: result = sorted(list) and the print(result)

Answer (score 2):

```py
lst = [('Betty', 42.5), ('Andrew', 46.5), ('Zach', 49), ('Cathy', 42.5), ('Jay', 45.5), ('Kevin', 45), ('Cassie', 41), ('Matt', 44), ('Jamie', 44.5), ('Xavier', 45.5), ('Peter', 45.5), ('John', 42.5), ('Jamie', 40.5), ('Joe', 40.5), ('Ellen', 44.5), ('Nancy', 35), ('Jay', 45), ('Bryce', 43.5), ('Gordon', 37), ('Gee', 42.5)]

n0 = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True) 
n1 = sorted(n0, key=lambda x: x[0])
print(n1)
```

Comment: Thank you, because it requires higher score first so I add reverse=True in n0. It works.

Answer (score 1):

it is never good to re-use a name like `list` which already has a use in Python, so I changed it to `data`. If you negate numbers for sorting purposes, then although 40.5 is less than 44.5, -44.5 is less than -40.5, so if sorting would put the minimum number first, that same sort but on the *negation* of that numeric field puts the **maximum** first.

Here is that idea in action:

```
In [1]: data = [('Betty', 42.5), ('Andrew', 46.5), ('Zach', 49), ('Cathy',     
   ...: 42.5), ('Jay', 45.5), ('Kevin', 45), ('Cassie', 41), ('Matt', 44),     
   ...: ('Jamie', 44.5), ('Xavier', 45.5), ('Peter', 45.5), ('John', 42.5), 
   ...: ('Jamie', 40.5), ('Joe', 40.5), ('Ellen', 44.5), ('Nancy', 35), 
   ...: ('Jay', 45), ('Bryce', 43.5), ('Gordon', 37), ('Gee', 42.5)]

In [2]: sorted(data)
Out[2]: 
[('Andrew', 46.5),
 ('Betty', 42.5),
 ('Bryce', 43.5),
 ('Cassie', 41),
 ('Cathy', 42.5),
 ('Ellen', 44.5),
 ('Gee', 42.5),
 ('Gordon', 37),
 ('Jamie', 40.5),
 ('Jamie', 44.5),
 ('Jay', 45),
 ('Jay', 45.5),
 ('Joe', 40.5),
 ('John', 42.5),
 ('Kevin', 45),
 ('Matt', 44),
 ('Nancy', 35),
 ('Peter', 45.5),
 ('Xavier', 45.5),
 ('Zach', 49)]

In [3]: sorted(data, key=lambda x:(x[0], -x[1]))
Out[3]: 
[('Andrew', 46.5),
 ('Betty', 42.5),
 ('Bryce', 43.5),
 ('Cassie', 41),
 ('Cathy', 42.5),
 ('Ellen', 44.5),
 ('Gee', 42.5),
 ('Gordon', 37),
 ('Jamie', 44.5),
 ('Jamie', 40.5),
 ('Jay', 45.5),
 ('Jay', 45),
 ('Joe', 40.5),
 ('John', 42.5),
 ('Kevin', 45),
 ('Matt', 44),
 ('Nancy', 35),
 ('Peter', 45.5),
 ('Xavier', 45.5),
 ('Zach', 49)]

In [4]:
```

Jamie and Jay have there maximum number first without needing dual sorts and reversals.

Comment: This is great, more explanation at [this link](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/in-python-you-sort-with-a-tuple)

Comment: ... Except the linked article just states you can negate, with no extra help on why it works.